# Google SERP with image on left

Tags: rich-snippets

i recently saw on Google a new kind of image for rich snippets. [image: search results for sizzling shot in romania]

And i wonder how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I fond the solution. For a arcade gaming site you can make a video sitemap so google will index your website with video thumbnails. :)